# Function to only load a page if the user is logged in and has a certain UID?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

Right now I have a a basic login page with Firebase. However I want to know how I only load web pages if someone has a certain UID and they are logged in.

Right now I have:

```
    <h3 style="color: white;">Welcome User</h3>
    <p id="user_para" style="color: white;">Welcome to Firebase web login Example. You're currently logged in.</p>
    <button onclick="logout()">Logout</button>
  </div>
```

But there is a problem with this. It is on the client side meaning anyone can see the data in it. This will be a problem in the future because this website is going to be used for storing sensitive data. Does anyone know how I can write a rule/function to pull data from a page if the person is logged in and has a certain UID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data and files are coming from the Realtime Database and Cloud Storage, you can secure access to those by using Firebase's [server-side security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules). There are many use-cases you can implement with these, so I recommend reading the linked documentation end-to-end. But if you want to allow read access to a specific, known UID (say `uidOfKnownUser`), that'd be:

*For Realtime Database*:

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": "auth.uid === 'uidOfKnownUser'"
    }
  }
}
```

*For Cloud Storage*:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /{anyFile=**} {
    // Allow the request if the following conditions are true.
    allow read : if request.auth.uid === 'uidOfKnownUser'
  }
}
```

For files on Cloud Storage, keep in mind that download URLs are no secured by these rules. So anyone who has a download URL for a file, can ready that file.

---

If your HTML and JavaScript are hosted on Firebase Hosting, then there's no way to protect access to them as all resources on Firebase Hosting are readable by anyone who knows their URL.

If you're hosting your HTML and JavaScript elsewhere, check the documentation for that product to see if it allows restricting access to specific users.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do it, you should have some file to check the db and response with true/false.. here is my file `FileToCheckDataBase`

```
function CheckUid(uid) {
      var xhttp;
         xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           //here is the answer from file after checking in db
           if(this.response==1){
           //user uid is ok
           //do something.. usually continue
           }
           else{
             //  kick him out
           }
          }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "FileToCheckDataBase?uid="+uid, true);
      xhttp.send();
  
  }
```